# Using the CDN on asp.net with scriptmanager

Tags: asp.net, cdn

On reading the asp.net cdn site I read the following

When using ASP.NET 4, you can redirect all requests for ASP.NET framework scripts to the CDN. Retrieving scripts from the CDN instead of your local web server can substantially improve the performance of public ASP.NET websites.

Use the ScriptManager EnableCDN property to redirect all ASP.NET framework script requests to the Microsoft Ajax CDN:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableCdn="true" Runat="Server" />
```

Does this mean on the template asp.net website the scriptmanager that is created on the masterpage is removed including the scripts under it?

For example, are we to remove this;

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
        <%--Framework scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site scripts--%>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and replace it with;

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableCdn="true" Runat="Server" />
```

Will that CDN now deliver all files we request including jquery and its subsets and the ajax control toolkit files?